# iOS, UIView animation, animate own content

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

i have a subclass of UIView that displays own content.  I'd like to animate the content.

The content is self-drawn in an own drawRect:, i wonder what possibilities are there to animate it.  The content itself consists of graphical shapes that change their form.

I don't see a way to construct the content with subviews that can then be animated themselves.

Is there a way to use an UIView animation block?

Are there other possibilities?  I would not want to animate this using OpenGL ES, this would be my last choice.

Thanks for any hints
Torsten

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you can't use CALayer? They are made for this! You can create complex frames/textures (you wrote you have geometric shapes) and apply animated transforms to them.

Consider that if your shapes don't fit in the (really wide array of possibility) of shapes, you can basically draw any line using a CALayer: you create a layer of the proper length and width then simply translate and rotate it as needed (and of course translation an rotation are "animatable").

Comment: thanks for the hint, but i'm pretty sure that i can't use animations of rotation / translation (any other animation of the transformation matrix) to do what i want.  Imagine animating the single points of a filled polygon, maybe this is comparable.

Comment: can you give me more details? how many shapes we are speaking about? how they should change?